# How do I access content from the Cerberus Network DLC?

Tags: ps3, mass-effect-2

I've entered the serial code and downloaded the Cerberus Network DLC from the PSN store. I then installed the pack and launched the game.

The [Mass Effect wiki says](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Cerberus_Network):

> On the main Mass Effect 2 start screen, there is a second computer on the right-hand desk that opens to show the Cerberus Daily News and any new DLC that is available.

I pressed triangle to connect to the EA servers, but the computer on the right hand portion of the screen won't open.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be obvious, but are you sure your PS3 is connected to the PSN when you start the game? Also, keep in mind that most of the DLC for Mass Effect 2 isn't started separately from a different menu, it's woven into the game proper. You'll get messages from people on your terminal to go to a planet or something along those lines.

Comment: Two good points. I'm definitely connected to the PSN. And I've been able to do some of the DLC missions, so I guess it's just the start screen that isn't playing nicely.

Comment: I'd forgotten this, but Bioware have essentially shut down the Cerberus Network updates (http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/106564-BioWare-Shuts-Down-Cerberus-Network-Confirms-New-Mass-Effect-DLC), so that's probably why nothing is happening. I'm not at home to check if the same is happening on my PC. But if you can play the DLC then I don't think you have anything to worry about :)

Comment: The DLC is still available, it is just the daily random updates are gone.